# Проблема функции запроса pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Вот мой код:

```
<?php
 class DB {

    private static function connect() {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=social;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
            $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($params);

            if (explode(' ', $query)[0] == 'SELECT') {
            $data = $statement->fetchAll();
            return $data;
            }
    }

}

DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :password, :email, \'0\', \'\')', array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), ':email'=>$email));

?>
```

код ошибки:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sn2\classes\DB.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sn2\classes\DB.php(12): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sn2\create-account.php(22): DB::query('INSERT INTO use...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sn2\classes\DB.php on line 12
```

---

### База даних 100% подключена...

---

Comment: вы попытались перевести сообщение об ошибке? написано же вроде, количество вставляемых значений не соответствует их числу столбцов в таблице.

Comment: но по моему интересней то, что в ошибке приведен запрос `insert into use..`, которого нет в коде вопроса.

Comment: исправил на тот запрос  что нужно

Comment: Спасибо! действительно количество вставляемых значений не соответствует их числу столбцов в таблице